# Do I have to build maven webapp project everytime i make changes into static files?

Tags: spring, maven, web-applications, jboss7.x

I am using JBOSS AS7.1, Eclipse Luna for development. My eclipse installation does have a plugin installed for maven.

I have created my webapp project using maven command-line.

In my current set up, I have to build my maven project using `mvn clean install` every time for all changes, even for the static files like HTML, CSS.

Then, I have to deploy the generated WAR file using JBOSS console running at `http://localhost:9990/console`.

I am quite sure that there must be another way to do this. Surely, it does take a hell lot of time.

Please guide me to the approaches I can adopt for faster development.

Comment: I am using JBOSS AS 7 server.

Comment: No. There isn't any specific need for JBOSS. But as a developer, I would prefer my development and testing environment to be same.

Answer (score 3):

One option is [jrebel](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/). It's not free though.

If you are not bound to JBOSS, you could use spring boot. It also supports automatic restart ([spring boot devtools](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart))

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the static file in your target folder and launch a build skipping the `compile` phase.

It will save you a lot of time, when only updating static files.

It is not a good practice, but should let you achieve your goal.

**How to**:

- Use the `maven-clean-plugin` to remove the files to replace from the target folder (or they will not be overwritten);
- Use the `resources` tag if your static files are not the only content of the resources folder you want to copy (or your static files are not in *resources* folder at all);
- Use the `maven-compiler-plugin` to skip the compile phase.

Customize this profile (and use it with `mvn clean install -P skip-compile`):

```
<profile>
    <id>skip-compile</id>
    <build>
        <resources> <!-- optional -->
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/META-INF</directory>
                <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.html</include>
                    <include>**/*.css</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF</directory>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/not_to_delete.xml</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.html</include>
                                <include>**/*.css</include>
                            </includes>
                            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skipMain>true</skipMain>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Comment: Accepted answer just 2 hours after the bounty end... >.>